# Two square brackets side by side: strange effect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was on a competitive programming site, and found a guy who wrote this strange (to me) Python 3 code:

```
[r,"Nothing"][r==""]
```

It outputs `'Nothing'`, if `r` is the empty string.

How is this called and what does it mean? It looks like a ternary operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is this called and what does it mean? It looks like a ternary operator.

There's no official name for it in Python AFAIK; it's just a sneaky, convoluted way of indexing a list, really.

You'll select `"Nothing"` if `r==""` is `True` and `r` if `r == ''` is `False`; as an example:

```
>>> [0, 1][True]
1
>>> [0, 1][False]
0
```

since `True` and `False` are interpreted as `1` and `0` respectively, when you index the list.

The snippet provided just defines a temporary list with the two elements `[r, "Nothing"]` and then indexes it using the `True/False` result of the comparison of `r` with the empty string `[r=='']`.

Not the most readable code and probably not the best idea to create a list which you don't plan on using; it can be easily substituted by the conditional expression:

```
"Nothing" if r == "" else r
```

more readable and a lot more efficient:

```
%timeit True if False else False
10000000 loops, best of 3: 32.9 ns per loop

%timeit [False, True][False]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 176 ns per loop
```

no need to create a list and no need to subscript it; just a conditional and some loading.

Answer (score 1):

It translates to:

```
if (r==""):
  'Nothing'
else:
  r
```

`False` in this context is used as 0, and `True` as 1:

```
>>> [r,'Nothing'][False]
'foo'
>>> [r,'Nothing'][True]
'Nothing'
```

It's a one-liner similar to `'condition'?'if true':'if false'` in other languages. It's usually used in [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) where you have to produce the shortest code possible.